# :t in shell script

Tags: shell, tcl, csh

I am trying to understand the :t in following code but could not figure out and these piece of code need to convert in tcl. When We print it split the word the on the slash and it return the last element. ex:  user3,user,etc

suppose d = /home/etc/user/user3

```
while 1 {
  set _f $_d:t  
   }
```

Comment: What shell is that, exactly?

Comment: it is simple shell script

Comment: If it were, I would recognise the syntax. What shell is it *exactly*?

Comment: Looks like it is `csh`, where the `:t` modifier on a history substitution or variable assignment takes the tail of the referred-to filename.

Comment: @user765443, when you're being asked "what the shell is", the person who asks wants to know what is the script's "shebang" is (that `#!/path/to/the/program` line at the top of the script) or what binary is explicitly used to interpret the script etc. There's no abstract "the shell" on Unix systems.

Comment: it is my bad luck. ya it it csh shell. Sincerely appology  from my side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably looking for `file tail`:

```
set _f [file tail $_d]
```

It's not normally good style to start a Tcl variable name with `_`, but it's quite legal to do so if you want to.

Comment: You could put it in a `while 1 {`…`}` if you want, but that would be an incredibly odd thing to do.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I had another query in TCL.

Comment: if we have directory in following way. path= /home/etc/user. if we want to write in loop. we should get result in following way. (/home/etc) and (/home). /user should be discard. Please consider me as new person in tcl